# Change Hex value for a color resource at runtime

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to change the value of a color resource at runtime?
The reason for changing the color is to globally change color schemes for my UI depending on the state of the application. I have custom shapes for the UI elements that make use of these color resources and if I were able to change the values of the colors at runtime , then I can change the color of my UI elements based on the state the application is in. Its much more efficient to change one color value rather than changing the color of every UI element since the same colors are used in many places on the UI.

As an example the following would be my color.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="custom_color_1">#ff5500</color>  
   <color name="custom_color_2">#fbe18d</color> 
   <color name="custom_color_3">#38302d</color> 
   <color name="custom_color_4">#50b2fa</color>
</resources>
```

then in my drawables directory I have custom shape files for various UI elements such as a round button,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
    <item>         
        <shape  android:shape="oval">             
            <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/custom_color_1" 
            android:endColor="@color/custom_color_2" 
            android:angle="270"
            />         
        </shape>     
    </item> 

    <item 
    android:top="1dp" 
    android:left="1dp" 
    android:right="1dp" 
    android:bottom="1dp">         

        <shape android:shape="oval">             
            <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/custom_color_3" 
            android:endColor="@color/custom_color_4" 
            android:angle="270"
            />         
        </shape>     
    </item> 

</layer-list>
```

So by being able to change the color resource value at runtime, I can change these UI elements at runtime. Hope thats clear.

Thanks

Comment: then color will change. is this ok to you?

Comment: @depsch: I think you should add some more information about the environment/programming language you are using so that the question can be answered correctly. Use multipe tags to describe the environment and add some additional information.